# parse ajax response text

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, xmlhttprequest

I want to update the web page based on ajax response received from a php script.

code inside php page :

// based on the logic either of the following three will be returned using ajax repsonse.

```
echo "<div align='center>Yahoo</div>";

echo "<div align='center>Rediff</div>";

echo "<div align='center>Google</div>";
```

The page which calls the ajax and receive the repsonse needs to perform some actions based on the returned response text.

Like , when the reponse includes "Yahoo" i need to execute some javascript functions....
when the reponse includes "Rediff" i need to perform some other javascript functions....

Currently i am using the `javascript .indexOf function` to search for "Yahoo" or "Rediff" in the ajax response and based on the return status of `.indexOf()` i am calling the functions i wish to execute.....

**I feel i am not doing it in the right way ..... so thats why this question !!!**

Can JSON be used in this case ??? [ just a tech thought :-) ]

Comment: yes with json you can simply determin if(data['google']) or if any thing else

Comment: `Can JSON be used in this case`. Absolutely and I would even advise using it to accomplish what you want :)

Answer (score 0):

i use json quite a lot for ajax apps, you could simply have a response such as

```
{
    "response":"rediff",
}
```

then eval that, and get the .response value. works perfectly for me

the response from the php script would be the same as above, then (the way i interpret json) use

```
var resp = eval("("+req.responseText+")");
resp = resp.response;
```

resp will now return "rediff"

Comment: Can u pls help with a short code snippet as i nvr used JSON ... jst heard of it.. and i am NOT using jquery but using vanilla javascript

Comment: @Sandy505 edited the post with some code for you, hope it helps

Comment: How do i return json response from my php code ? the req object can contain other response also. I am jst confused ... would really appreciate if you could assist me with this with a code snippet where from php we can return a normal text with php echo command and some repsonse values using json.

Comment: @Sandy505 As for returning the response, instead of returning an HTML document, it returns the json element. I used ob_start to and ob_get_content to clear new lines, and pulled with XHR. It doesn't have to contain just one response, it can contain multiple values, either just single strings, objects or arrays. For my usage, "response" referred to an array, and then I used a for(var i=0; i<resp.length; i++) and looped through all the items in the array and used that to create objects using document.createElement(resp[i].element) and then parentObject.appendChild(<!--object above-->).

Comment: came across this wonderful [tutorial](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2005/12/the_ajax_respon.html) after your inputs ..... trying to grasp it now....

Comment: @Sandy505 yup, thats pretty much the way I do it. Except when it comes to creating objects, I like to create an array called attributes, and then it loops through those, applying the value to the key (which matches a few common operators, such as ID, onclick, class, specific styles, etc)